# XFCE online help on Ctrl-C

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xfce, xfce4-terminal

I'm running Xubuntu. The terminal has started popping up a dialog

> Do you want to read the Xfce Terminal Manual Online?

every time I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.  This has rendered emacs (among others) basically unusable, and I can't figure out how to change the configuration.  I haven't played with any config files recently, so I'm not sure why this behavior has started. It's possible that I upgraded the package.

Any idea how to disable this?  Where is the relevant setting?

If it matters, I use the Dvorak keyboard layout, which occasionally messes up commands.  On the hardware keyboard, the command in question is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>.  However, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> still works as expected in other programs.